# Who are the amalekites today?

Tags: amalek

I am wondering which nation are the amalekites today. I have heard that they are either Germany or Russia. I think Russia, but also others have said that amalek had assimilated into a few nations, like the Arabs and others.

Comment: See Toldot Yaakov Yosef about Shedm Yudayim

Comment: Can u give me a link or something to that

Comment: Definitely the Arbs or Nazis. Not Russias. Although Russians have harmed Jews, Rasputin, Leo Tolstoy, as well as Putin, support/ed Jews in Russia.